# Tab Bar Item title before appear Storyboard

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

my app starts with a tab bar controller which have 5 tabs. At start the first one in presented with its name but the other four don't have a name until I click on them. Then the name appears depending which language the user has.
How can I set the name of the tabs before the tab bar appears?
I am using storyboard. Is there a way to set title at the tab bar programmatically when all the rest is done with storyboard? I tried in the AppDelegate something like `[FirstViewController setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Titel1", nil)];`
But I got an error that there is no class method for selector setTitle.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem today. I'm using storyboard too. In my case i used the following way.

1. I've created a new "Objective-C class" with the name
   "MainTabBarViewController" as a subclass of "UITabBarController".
2. In my storyboard in "identity inspector" i changed "Custom class" to "MainTabBarViewController".
3. In the method "viewDidLoad" in "MainTabBarViewController" i added:

   [[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"home", nil)];

   [[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"statistics", nil)];

   [[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"settings", nil)];

   [[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3] setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"info", nil)];

I guess it is not the perferct way, but for me it works perfect.

Comment: I can't believe it!! I've been looking for this solution for so long. Thank you so much :)

Comment: See my solution below, it doesn't require setting titles with indices.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works for updating the UITabBarItem images too.

Answer (score 2):

I had a configuration with two tabs like this:

```
MainTabBarController : UITabBarController
    +- MessagesNavigationController : UINavigationController
    +- ContactsNavigationController : UINavigationController
```

In a configuration with Storyboard and ARC I overrode the `initWithCoder:` selector in the custom classes of my UITabBarController view controllers (in this case `ContactsNavigationController`) and initialized the `tabBarItem.title` there like this:

```
@implementation ContactsNavigationController

...

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Contacts", nil);
    }
    return self;
}
```

When using storyboards the iOS calls `(id)initWithCoder:` instead of `-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` when the storyboard view controller is initialized during UITabBarController launch. Also note that `viewDidLoad` doesn't get called until the view controller tab is selected from the tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

In the app delegate, where you are creating the view controllers, set the title property here (rather than in `viewDidLoad`), for example:

```
vc1 = [[VC1 alloc] init];
vc1.title = @"List";

vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] init];
vc2.title = @"Map";

tabBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];
```

Comment: I am using storyboard. So I created them in storyboard. Is there another way to do this in storyboard?

Comment: I don't know as I don't use storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the FirstViewController created by Xcode using the template Tab-Bar application based in the `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` method you can see something like this:

```
if (self) {  
    //check your language
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"First", @"First");
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];  
}
```

So you have to check for your language and then set the `title` property, this will set the title on the tab bar and in the navigation bar.

Comment: I have a Tab Bar View Controller in Storyboard and when it is presented I want all tab bar title to be shown depending which language the user has configured in his iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in every view u have to use this method

Suppose this is you first view

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"homepage", @"homepage");
        [self.tabBarItem setTag:0];
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"homepage"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In you app delegate class write this code to add `UITabBarController`

```
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,viewController4,viewController5, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Add above code in

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {}
```

Comment: i don't know about the story bored  but it will defiantly work in other projects